# return multiple values from database

Tags: php, php-5.4, php-5.5

i am trying to echo two values from database and want to echo that value in separate places in html but when i call that function in html it gives me both value in the same place but i want that value in different places how to do that help please.

HTML

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <a href="home.php?q=logout">LOGOUT</a>
        </div>
        <div id="main-body">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <h1>
              Hello <?php $user->get_fullname($uid); ?>

              <?php echo $uid; ?>
            </h1>   
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

php function in a class name User

```
    public function get_fullname($uid){
        $sql3="SELECT fullname,uemail FROM users WHERE uid = $uid";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql3);
        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo $user_data['fullname'];
        echo $user_data['uemail'];

    }
```

Comment: You should become familiar with concept of templates (and relevant packages, like Blade, Smarty etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function get_fullname($uid){
        $sql="SELECT fullname,uemail FROM users WHERE uid = $uid";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql);
        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        return (object)array('username'=>$user_data['fullname'],'email'=>$user_data['uemail']);
    }
    /* Call the class method - doesn't echo back to screen */
    $userdata=$user->get_fullname($uid);
```

Then, later in the code:

```
echo $userdata->username; 
/* or */
echo $userdata->email
```

One thing however, perhaps you ought to investigate `prepared statements` for use with `mysqli`

Comment: its gives me error (Undefined variable: userdata in)

Comment: thank you sooo much script have only one error that is in line 3 ($sql3) that script is very nice thanks again

Comment: well spotted @SherazKhan